# HazelCast - What happens if the backup as well as original node holding ILock fail at the same time

Tags: hazelcast

If I have 4 nodes running in a cluster and I am using ILock functionality of hazelcast. What happens in case both the main node storing Lock information and the backup node lose power at the same time. There will be data loss but will hazelcast pick up next available machine to provide locks without throwing exceptions?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try calling lock method again after the crash? It should go to the available machine.